# performance hit at bitwise operation

Tags: c++, c, assembly, bitwise-operators

```
// nx_, ny_ is like 350 * 350
#define   IJ_REF(_i, _j) ((_j)*nx_+(_i))
#define HAS_BIT(_v, _bit)     (((_v) & (_bit)) == (_bit))

for (int ix = 0; ix < nx_; ++ix) {              // 0.019s
    for (int iy = 0; iy < ny_; ++iy) {          // 0.716s
        int32 r = IJ_REF(ix, iy);               // 0.548s
        if (!HAS_BIT(image_[r], FLAG)) {        // 3.016s
            int32 k = r * 4;                    // 0.242s
            pTex[k] = pTex[k + 1] = pTex[k + 2] = pTex[k + 3] = 255;  // 1.591s
        }
    }
}
```

The assembly of the HAS_BIT line is:
[image]

I guess the `and` directive is a `&` operation, so is it suppose to be so costly?

PS: FLAG is 0x2 so I guess the compiler did some optimization to generate a single directive for the `HAS_BIT`. And I use Vtune to profile.

Comment: You shouldn't start your identifiers with underscores.  Those identifiers are reserved for your compiler's implementation.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie those are macro definitions which will be replaced before compilation, but you are right, I shouldn't.

Comment: The and itself shouldn't be costly but perhaps you're confusing the crap out of the branch predictor, especially if there's no real pattern to whether or not that condition is true. Then you spend a lot of time waiting for the pipeline to flush.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The hit is not because you are using a bit-wise instruction, but because the instruction reads from memory - a more expensive operation than offset computation that uses registers.

The problem with the code is that it does not read memory consecutively, because according to `IJ_REF` your image is stored by rows, but you read it by column.

You should be able to improve the performance by increasing the number of cache hits if you swap the order of your loops:

```
for (int iy = 0; iy < ny_; ++iy) {
    for (int ix = 0; ix < nx_; ++ix) {
        int32 r = IJ_REF(ix, iy);
        if (!HAS_BIT(image_[r], FLAG)) {
            int32 k = r * 4;
            pTex[k] = pTex[k + 1] = pTex[k + 2] = pTex[k + 3] = 255;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case wouldn't you expect to see the larger time on the preceding movzx line?

Comment: @JasonC I am not 100% sure if the profiler has attributed the timing correctly here, but you are right, the reading instruction is on the `movzx` line.

Comment: That's right, the swap result in a 50% drop of time consumption. Again the compiler may not timing perciselly at the directive level. But the overall time also dropped by 40%-50%.

Comment: The profiler probably measures things correctly. The load starts quickly, but the CPU doesn't wait for it to finish until the result of that load is actually needed. And that happens when the register we're loading is used, in the and instruction. This is why profiling on an instruction level is pretty much useless today. You shouldn't think about single lines of code or instructions. Timing bottlenecks happen on whole large sections of code or even whole programs.

Answer (score 1):

Can you profile this variant (without branching) and post the result? I'm curious... (may be slower, if you write those 255 into pTex rarely, as this code will touch every pTex byte with `or`).

```
#include <string>

#define IJ_REF(_i, _j) ((_j)*nx_+(_i))
#define HAS_BIT(_v, _bit)     (((_v) & (_bit)) == (_bit))

int main()
{
    constexpr uint32_t ny_ = 350, nx_ = 350;
    constexpr uint8_t FLAG = 2;
    uint8_t image_[ny_*nx_];
    uint8_t pTex[ny_*nx_*4];

    // let access pTex by uint32_t directly
    uint32_t *pTex32bPtr = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(pTex);

    // debug input
    image_[IJ_REF(nx_-2, ny_-1)] = FLAG;
    image_[IJ_REF(nx_-1, ny_-1)] = ~FLAG;
    pTex32bPtr[IJ_REF(nx_-2, ny_-1)] = 0x12345678;
    pTex32bPtr[IJ_REF(nx_-1, ny_-1)] = 0x12345678;

    // prepare for loop
    const uint32_t endOfs = ny_*nx_;
    constexpr uint32_t pTexORValue[2] = {0, 0xFFFFFFFF};
    // loop trough all [x,y] values
    for (uint32_t srcOfs = 0; srcOfs < endOfs; ++srcOfs) {
        unsigned ORindex = !HAS_BIT(image_[srcOfs], FLAG);
        // if you know FLAG is always 2, it can be:
        // ORindex = image_[srcOfs]&2; with pTexORValue array:
        // [3] = {0xFFFFFFFF, 0, 0};
        pTex32bPtr[srcOfs] |= pTexORValue[ORindex];
    }

    // debug output
    for (size_t i = IJ_REF(nx_-2, ny_-1) * 4; i < IJ_REF(nx_, ny_-1)*4; ++i) {
        printf(" %02x", pTex[i]);
    }
}
```

---

Also I sort of wonder, why your compiler does `movzx edx` + `and edx`, while it could do `test byte ptr [eax+ecx],2` instead. What is type of `FLAG`? Oh, now I see, it's because of your `HAS_BIT` macro. It's actually "has_all_bits" test.

If you plan to test only single bit, or any-of-bits is good, you should try (this should allow for `test` usage):

```
#define HAS_SOME_BIT(_v, _bits)     (((_v) & (_bits)) != 0)
```

It may help even that code I posted above to be optimized better.

---

And in assembly with FLAG fixed as 2 it would be even possible to calculate the OR value as:

```
    mov    ebx,image_offset
loop:
    movzx  eax,Image_[ebx]
    ; copy bit 0x02 to all 32 bits
    shl    eax,30
    sar    eax,31
    not    eax     ; flip it to "not HAS_BIT"
    or     pTex[ebx*4],eax
    ...
```